# Blank, Null, and Required in Django Models and ModelForms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So far I haven't come across a clear explanation on blank, null, and required - in Django's models and forms.

---

*I know the default for each is the following:*

```
blank = False
null = False
required = True
```

*I also know that:*

`blank=True`  (used in models.py), means on the form level, accept empty forms - the associated field is not required in a form.

`null=True`  (used in models.py),  means on the database level that Python `None` values can be stored in the model and be saved (and then end up as SQL `NULL` values in the database).

`required=False`  (used in forms.py), means the associated form field is not required.

---

Hopefully the above information will serve others well (please let me know if there are any flaws in the logic, and I will update it).

My question is the following:

When do I know when to use `blank=True` vs. `required=False`. If my goal is to make a form field not required, I could define this in the model using `blank=True`, or I could define this in the form using `required=False`. Does this mean you can define `blank=True` in a model, and in the associated `ModelForm` override this with `required=True`?

Also related, what about when you are using a regular form (`forms.Form`)? Since the form is not associated with a model (other than through view logic), what happens if again, they contradict each other?

Comment: When *what* contradicts what, if a form isn't associated with a model.

Answer (score 22):

The contradictions don't matter. I think this brings flexibility to the development of a Django application. For example, if you're using a third party library that defines some models, and they set `blank=True`, but for other purposes you need that field is mandatory, then in your forms you can fix it without touching the third party library code.

This just add some flexibility to the framework IMHO, that brings no harm. You can use it for your own purposes. The contradictions are not significant.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks again, this makes sense, and also gives a lot more power to forms.

Comment: It's a great answer, which explain the reason and its use case.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the requirement. Sometime we decide later to make field mandatory on the form although on model it is still not required. But the form will ensure that field must be fill.

You can have `null=True` on the model and then later you can make that field mandatory on form. But you can not make a field optional in form when it is mandatory on model that will result in database error later on.

Comment: The field will be mandatory on the form if `null=True` in the model. Only `blank=True` in the Model sets `required=False` in the corresponding ModelForm. I have been burned by this un-intuitive aspect of model forms before